# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord Application crashed in Android 10.0 OS

Tags: android

1.I have started a forground service from mainActivity. Also added permission in manifest file android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE but application is crashing.

2.Application is working bellow 9.0 but crashing in android 10.

```
    public class SocketService extends Service {   
             @Override   
            public void onCreate() {   
                super.onCreate();       

            mCommunicationThread = new Thread(new SocketThread());      
            mCommunicationThread.start();   

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {   
                        String channel = createNotificationChannel(getString(R.string.app_name), "Service");   
                        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel)    
                                .setContentTitle("Name")//.build();      
                                .setContentText("Do not close it").build();   
                        startForeground(10012, notification);               
                    }  
        }  
      /**
         * Thread class which runs in background to accept data which is received
        from server via socket
         */      

          private class SocketThread implements Runnable {          
                @Override    
                public void run() {     

                     }       
                }         


        /**
           Create notification channel
         */
             private String createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName) {    
                    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId,    
                            channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);    
                    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);    
                    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);       
                    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)        
              getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);     
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);    
                    return channelId;    
                } 


        }       
          /**
           Start service from MainActivity
         */

           Intent intentService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SocketService.class);    
          this.startForegroundService(intentService);
```

Comment: please share you crash log

Comment: When app build in release mode app crashed. So i had added only google crash report. another error is 
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Comment: share complete error log

Comment: #00  pc 000000000001f1ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d7c50  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 0000000000519038  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*) (.llvm.268574309)+448)
  #03  pc 0000000000518e34  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+28)


  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:181)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7073)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider replacing `this.startForegroundService(intentService)` by `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intentService)`

Service are manage differently pre-O and post-O with `ContextCompat` it'll do the check :

```java
public static void startForegroundService(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        // Pre-O behavior.
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

PS: You might need to override `onHandleIntent` in your service to call `startForeground`

If your application still crashes, update your initial post and give us the log.

Comment: Try but not solved...same app crashed after release apk install in device.Build apk working fine

Comment: Take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and [medium](https://medium.com/@kalpeshchandora12/know-android-services-better-853a412d6775).

Comment: this solution will not work.